# Use of EXISTS in query can improve the performance?

Tags: postgresql

I have following query where I used DISTINCT as there is association so it gives duplicate values. But Is it possible to achieve it using EXIST as well?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cl.id)
    cl.id,
    cl.cid,
    cl.name
FROM locations cl
JOIN prop_loc pl ON (cl.cid = pl.cid AND cl.id = pl.loc_id)
JOIN prop_loc_prob plp ON (plp.cid = pl.cid AND plp.prop_id = pl.prop_id AND plp.loc_id = pl.loc_id)
JOIN prop_prob pp ON (plp.cid = pp.cid AND plp.prop_id = pp.prop_id AND plp.prob_id = pp.prob_id)
WHERE
    pl.prop_id = 12345 AND
    pl.cid = 123 
ORDER BY cl.id, cl.name
```

Can we use the following two strict JOINS in EXISTS? Does it improve sql performance?

```
JOIN prop_loc_prob plp ON (plp.cid = pl.cid AND plp.prop_id = pl.prop_id AND plp.loc_id = pl.loc_id)
JOIN prop_prob pp ON (plp.cid = pp.cid AND plp.prop_id = pp.prop_id AND plp.prob_id = pp.prob_id)
```

Comment: Check the different query plans, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for the different queries

Answer (score 2):

All output columns come from table `locations`. Move all the rest into an `EXISTS` subquery expression. Then you can drop aggregation completely (no `GROUP BY`):

Compare performance of all candidate queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```sql
SELECT cl.id, cl.cid, cl.name
FROM   locations cl
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT  -- can stay empty
   FROM   prop_loc      pl
   JOIN   prop_loc_prob plp USING (prop_id, loc_id, cid)
   JOIN   prop_prob     pp  USING (prop_id, cid)
   WHERE  pl.cid = cl.cid
   AND    pl.loc_id = cl.id
   AND    pl.prop_id = 12345
   AND    pl.cid = 123
   )
ORDER  BY cl.id, cl.name;
```